# How to sort an array in Vue.js 3?

Tags: vuejs3

I have an array of objects

```
let list = reactive([
{name : 'name', age :20},
{name : 'name', age :21},
{name : 'name', age :2},
]);
```

and using v-for, I am displaying the values of the object.
What I want to achieve is to sort the array on button click, and return the sorted array.
While sorting works, sorted value is not displayed in the front-end, and my guess is I am misunderstanding something in the reactivity of Vue 3.

P.S
The sorted array should not be computed property, as I need to dynamically add/remove the objects from it.

Thanks

Comment: `computed` is not different/separate state. It's the main state (`list`, in your case), but sorted (e.g: viewed differently). To edit `sorted` you edit `list` and `sorted` will automatically update, while remaining sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still you should use a sorted `computed`. Just add/remove values to/from original array, and your `computed` reactively reflect those changes.

```js
const list = reactive([
  {name : 'name', age :20},
  {name : 'name', age :21},
  {name : 'name', age :2},
]);

const sorted = computed(() => list.slice().sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)));

list.push({name: 'name', age: 30});
// sorted will be updated on the next tick
```